# How to Read json file which is more than 3GB and has duplicate columns in nested elements

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am working on Azure technologies and want to Read json file which is more than 3GB and has duplicate columns in nested elements.
I tried pyspark, data flow , pipeines. But no luck.
Could you please suggest which technique i could use?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail to get a useful answer - a sample (sanitized) of your JSON, what exactly you want to do with it after you read it, where you want to put it, etc.

Comment: Below is the sample structure
{
"Docs": [
{
"RunOn": "2020-04-03T04:50:28.1064257Z",
"Version": 1,
"Client": "All",
"DatabaseType": "Client",
"IndexName": "DeclarationLogs/Search",
"@metadata": {
"Raven-Entity-Name": "IndexUpdates",
"Raven-Clr-Type": "Cas.Common.Domain.DbModel.IndexUpdate.IndexUpdate, Cas.Root",
"Ensure-Unique-Constraints": [],
"@id": "IndexUpdates/0001",
"Last-Modified": "2020-04-03T04:50:28.1072484Z",
"Raven-Last-Modified": "2020-04-03T04:50:28.1072484",
"@etag": "01000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000001",
"Non-Authoritative-Information": false
}}] }

Comment: This json is ravenDB backup file and very huge. I need to read this , flatten it and store in synapse. But currently I am not even able to read or process it. I somehow renamed the duplicate columns but as it is very huge in size , it is giving out of memory error. I tried to process it using pyspark. If I try to read as a text then it reads. but if I read as json then it gives error. I tried to read this file with more cluster size then it gives duplicate column error which is difficut to find out as these columns are in nested elements upto 4-5th level.

Comment: Plz suggest the way to atleast split it in smaller files using pyspark or data flow or any other way possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Azure Data Factory Mapping data flow, you can split big JSON file to small partitions.

In the Sink, define the partitioning

[image]

Later, using data flow transform, you can drop the duplicate values.

[image]

Follow https://mssqldude.wordpress.com/2019/03/23/partition-large-files-with-adf-using-mapping-data-flows/ for partitioning and https://tech-tutes.com/2020/10/19/remove-duplicate-data-using-data-flow-in-azure-data-factory/ to drop duplicate values.

Comment: Useful info, but the OP is looking to handle duplicate columns. The above article is handling duplicate rows in json files..is it not?

Comment: Thanks, I tried the partitioning method , I tried all partitioning methods available. Set partitions from 10 to 400 and to default also. But it gives out of memory error like below.
I also increased the IR size and the cores of IR but no luck.
Job failed due to reason: Cluster ran into out of memory issue during execution.